# View function not getting called in Django

Tags: python, django

Here's the view.py. `show_checkout` is called and runs all the way to `return HttpResponseRedirect('/receipt/')`, but for some reason, `receipt` view isn't being fired. none of the print statements are working:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.core import urlresolvers
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

from ecomstore.checkout.forms import CheckoutForm
from ecomstore.checkout.models import Order, OrderItem
from ecomstore.checkout import checkout
from ecomstore.cart import cart
from django.core.context_processors import csrf

# Create your views here.
def show_checkout(request, template_name='checkout/checkout.html'):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    if cart.is_empty(request):
        cart_url = urlresolvers.reverse('show_cart')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(cart_url)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        postdata = request.POST.copy()
        form = CheckoutForm(postdata)
        if form.is_valid():
            response = checkout.process(request)
            order_number = response.get('order_number',0)
            print 'this is the order number: ' + str(order_number)
            error_message = response.get('message','')
            if order_number:
                request.session['order_number'] = order_number
#                receipt_url = urlresolvers.reverse('checkout_receipt')
                print request.session['order_number']
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/receipt/')

        else:
            error_message = 'Correct the errors below'
    else:
        form = CheckoutForm()
    page_title = 'Checkout'
    return render_to_response(template_name, locals(), context_instance= RequestContext(request))

##Currently this doesn't seem to be running
def receipt(request, template_name='checkout/receipt.html'):
    order_number = request.session.get('order_number','')
    print 'this is receipt order number: ' + str(order_number)
    if order_number:
        print 'in order_number'
        order = Order.objects.filter(id=order_number)[0]
        order_items = OrderItem.objects.filter(order=order)
        del request.session['order_number']
    else:
        print 'not in order number'
        cart_url = urlresolvers.reverse('show_cart')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(cart_url) 
    return render_to_response(template_name, locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Here is the checkout.urls:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from ecomstore import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('ecomstore.checkout.views',
                       (r'^$','show_checkout',{'template_name':'checkout/checkout.html','SSL':settings.ENABLE_SSL},'checkout'),
                       (r'^receipt/$','receipt',{'template_name':'checkout/receipt.html','SSL':settings.ENABLE_SSL},'checkout_receipt'),
)
```

and the urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

                       # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'ecomstore.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^ecomstore/', include('ecomstore.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
                       url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
                       (r'^', include('catalog.urls')),
                       (r'^cart/$', include('cart.urls')),
                       (r'^checkout/$', include('checkout.urls')),
                       (r'^receipt/$', include('checkout.urls')),

)
```

IMPORTANT: Also it's currently being forwarded to `localhost/cart`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your main urls.py, don't use "$" in the regex. That seems to have fixed it for me.

Comment: ugh that makes sense. Would you happen to know why I can't use `reverse()` here?

Comment: You should be able to, as long as the entry has a name. (Reverse works on my test copy of the code you post)

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that you mean /receipt/receipt

Comment: Tried that and it says Page Not Found

Comment: Could you try add this: `from django.shortcuts import redirect` then instead of returning HttpRedirect, use `return redirect('checkout_receipt')`

Comment: hm, not working. i think it has something to do with that i don't have that library...ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.

Comment: When you uncomment `receipt_url = urlresolvers.reverse('checkout_receipt')` what value does that print?